# Is it possible to create an Object when you have the Type as a String?

Tags: java

If I take a user inputted String in my program which contains the Object Type that I am trying to create, is there a way for me to create an instance of that object? Something like the below:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an Object Type: ");  
String str = sc.nextLine();
// for example user inputs "Integer"
// I now want to create an Integer Object
```

Comment: Class.forName(String) [Here's Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)